# What is the most effective way to provide single sign-on for two ASP.NET 4.5 MVC apps?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, single-sign-on

I have two ASP.NET 4.5 MVC apps and both are using the default authentication that is implemented when first creating the VS project (mode="none" in the web config). I have a requirement to provide the ability for a user to only have to log in one time and be authenticated in both apps. Whether the login screen is the same for both apps or either login screen from either app can be used for authenticating, I'd like to understand the most effective way (and hopefully also least complicated) to provide single sign-on capabilities between the two MVC apps. And ideally, the user accounts and user sessions would be created in one database and not in both databases. The apps are currently on different domains and the same server, but might be on different servers as some point.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the db mentioned in the connectionstring to another db (ideally used just for users) in both websites and run the aspnet_regsql.exe ( located in `[drive]:\\%windir%\Framework.NET\Versions\[yourversion].`) for the userdb.

It is a tool that prepares a db for th asp.net services.